# What kind of wood for supporting a heavy TV?

Tags: wood, furniture, tabletop

I have a 40Kg TV, which I want to rest on a table.
The table is sturdy and can support the weight of the TV. However the length of the table is too short, so I want to elongate it by putting on top of it a simple wood slab (orange in the image).

Is a glued wood panel (width of 2.7cm) strong enough to support safely the TV?
Please notice the size of each object shown in the image.
The legs of the TV exceed the table of around 12.5cm (5") on each side.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any real wood (or plywood) top of 1 inch nominal will be more than enough to support the small amount of cantilevered mass you have here. This is true even if it was not attached to the underlying table. Heck, even some of that Ikea foam-core stuff would probably be ok.

Your only concern at these dimensions is if the cantilevered mass will want to deform the material in the middle, causing it to warp. Maybe some poorer quality aggregates would do this, especially as they age.

If you do fasten it to the table with glue and metal fasteners, it isn't going anywhere. You could even use 1/2 or 3/4 inch plywood in this case.

Search the previous Q&A for references to the "sagulator" which can give you *some* idea of how wood deflects. But you can get a good feel for this simply by taking your material, overhanging 12cm over the edge of your workbeanch, and pressing on it with your hand. The amount of deflection you get, and how it bounces back gives you all the information you need.

Comment: Thanks jdv, I didn't know about the sagulator. I don't have the wood panel with me so I can't get a feel for its strength. I guess I will check it out in person at the store.